# Should I use SQLiteDatabase to store data?

Tags: android

One of the activities in my app is a listview which needs to display a list of hotels with various information such as name, address etc.  The user needs to be able to add or remove hotels.

I was wondering what the best way to store this data would be, should I use a SQLiteDatabase or some other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a brain, use it. How else do you think you're going to store such things as addresses, coordinates on a map, phone numbers, business ID numbers, etc... without a relational database?

My suggestion, go with your gut instinct, and learn SQL/SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different options for data storage on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

However, I would go right up and agree with eplewis89 and say that for what you're doing, an SQLiteDatabase is probably the way to go. If you're not familiar with it, the Notepad Tutorial is a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: SQLite Database provides many advantages in developing a data driven application.